# Error: "Implicit declaration" for device_create_with_groups

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to build a custom kernel for NVIDIA Jetson Tk-1 by following the instructions here: 
https://github.com/projectara/Android-wiki/wiki/Kernel-Only-Build-Instructions-for-Jetson-reference-platform

Everything goes well until the "Testing Your Custom Kernel" section:

> STEP 2. make greybus modules
>
> $ cd $JKB_ROOT/greybus
>
> $ make clean
>
> $ make ARCH=arm KERNELDIR=../kernel-out EXTRA_CFLAGS+=-fno-pic

Here is a snippet for the error I am getting:

> /home/jonah/ara_kernel/greybus/loopback.c: In function
>   'gb_loopback_probe': /home/jonah/ara_kernel/greybus/loopback.c:1207:2:
>   error: implicit declaration of function 'device_create_with_groups'
>   [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]   dev =
>   device_create_with_groups(&loopback_class,   ^
>   /home/jonah/ara_kernel/greybus/loopback.c:1207:6: warning: assignment
>   makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]   dev =
>   device_create_with_groups(&loopback_class,

the problem occurs in the loopback.c file, which uses the function device_create_with_groups(...)

Here is the loopback.c file:
https://github.com/projectara/greybus/blob/master/loopback.c

As I understand, this function is found in include/linux/device.h header file, but even if I add `#include <linux/device.h>` to the beginning of loopback.c, I get the same implicit declaration error.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with Linux kernel headers 4.5.0-040500-generic.

Am I using the wrong kernel headers or is the function deprecated or something?

I can get rid of the warning with a declaration in the function above it:

```
struct device *device_create_with_groups(struct class *class, struct device *parent, dev_t devt, void *drvdata, const struct attribute_group **groups, const char *fmt, ...);
```

but will this have any severe repercussions when I use the kernel?  Or will the function magically be found by the linker eventually?

Comment: There's nothing magic in software development! :)

Comment: Please post your answer if you resolved this issue

Comment: Actually, I just gave up.